# different behavior of shutil.move on Windows and Mac

Tags: shutil

Trying to move files from one directory to another. On a Mac, the following work fine. On a PC I get an error when the last file is reached saying it can't be moved because it is in use by another application or process. However, the file is moved (or a copy of is made) AND the original stays in the same location.

```
import sys, os
import shutil

sourcepath="D:\Data\MP-PO-to-QB\NEWXMLS"

for filename in os.listdir(sourcepath):
    current_file=os.path.join(sourcepath, filename)
    dst="D:\Data\MP-PO-to-QB\CONVERTED"
    shutil.move(current_file, dst)
```

Comment: How does it work on a mac when you are giving it a DOS path?

Comment: Yes, windows and Unix have different models for locking.  Windows does not allow locked files to be deleted, unix (and osx) generally do, but won't actually deallocate the file until the last reference to it is closed.

Comment: The path in the example is for the Windows machine. On the Mac I have tested it using paths that work on the Mac. I have verified that none of the files are locked (unless you mean something else).  Thanks

Comment: After some searching I found adding ""except WindowsError: [return + 4 spaces] pass"" does not give me anymore errors. However it copys the last file in the directory to the dst instead of moving. Now I'm stuck with 1 file in the src when I need the src to be empty.

Comment: Although I still don't know why this error happens, I was able to make my project work by taking out this shutil.move command and having it as a .bat file that would execute after the whole .py script was executed.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, if you open a file before moving it, you will get an error message like the following:

> PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process:

You should close the file before moving it.